# R Shiny: Switching datasets based on user input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am working on a shiny app where users can upload their own data and get some plots and statistics back. However, I also want to include an example dataset that gets used instead if the user presses a specific button. Importantly, the plots should be reactive so that users get updated plots whenever they click on the "use example data instead" button or upload a new file. I tried to recreate my current approach of overwriting the data object as best as I could here, but simply defining the data object twice doesn't overwrite the data in the way I hoped it would. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Reproducible Example"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

            fileInput("Upload", "Upload your own Data"),

            actionButton("Example", "Use Example Data instead")

        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(

            plotOutput("hist")

        )
    )
)

# Server Logic
server <- function(input, output) {

        data <- eventReactive(input$Upload,{input$Upload})
        data <- eventReactive(input$Example, {faithful$eruptions})

        output$hist <- renderPlot({hist(data())})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `reactiveVal` like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
   my_data <- reactiveVal()
   observeEvent(input$Upload, {
      tmp <- read.csv(input$Upload$datapath)
      ## do whatever is needed to parse the data
      my_data(tmp)
   })
   observeEvent(input$Example, {
      my_data(faithful)
   })
   output$hist <- renderPlot({
       dat <- as.data.frame(req(my_data()))
       dat <- dat[, sapply(dat, is.numeric), drop = FALSE]
       validate(need(NCOL(dat) > 1, "No numeric columns found in provided data"))
       hist(dat[,1])
   })
}
```

Depending on upload or button click, you store your data in `my_data` which is a reactive value. Whenever this value changes, the `renderPlot` function fires and uses the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reactive value to access whether the user has chosen to use an example dataset or use their own dataset. The user can choose to switch between the active dataset using an input from your UI.

Here's the official explanation on reactive values from RStudio: [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html)

This would go in your `ui.R`:

```
radioButtons("sample_or_real",    
    label = h4("User data or sample data?"),
    choices = list(
        "Sample Data" = "sample",
        "Upload from user data" = "user",
    ), 
    selected = "user"
)
```

This would go in your `server.R`:

```
data_active <- reactive({

  # if user switches to internal data, switch in-app data
  observeEvent(input$sample_or_real_button, {

  if(input$sample_or_real == "sample"){
    data_internal <- sample_data_object
  } else {
    data_internal <- uploaded_data_object
  }
})
```

Note, that when using a reactive value in your `server.R` file, it must have parentheses `()` at the end of the object name. So, you call the data_internal object as `data_internal()`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the code! I was thinking about this too and was reluctant to try it because I already have a lot of settings on the page with radio buttons and wanted to make the example a single button. I think I'll try thotals suggestion and fall back to the radio button method if I can't implement it.

Comment: Happy to help. I have been doing something similar with this app EviAtlas, if you want to check it out and lift some of the code: [github code](https://github.com/ESHackathon/eviatlas), [live app](https://estech.shinyapps.io/eviatlas/)